# Does parity matter for $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\ln 2 -\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\cdots -\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right)\right)^n =\sqrt{e}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\ln 2 -\left(-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14+\cdots  -\frac{(-1)^n}n\right)\right)^n =\sqrt{e}$$

I happened to encounter this problem proposed  by *Mohammed Bouras,Morocco* in the facebook [group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/355300697927549/permalink/1722753421182263/?app=fbl) of [Romanian mathematical Magazine](https://www.ssmrmh.ro/)

As per the  title,  I think the limit of the problem depends upon the parity of $n$. That is,if $n$ is even, the limit is $\frac1{\sqrt e}$ otherwise as stated.

My query is, **Does the parity indeed matters for this problem**? And if it matters **what should be  the conclusion for limit of the problem**?

**Here is my try**

we will show that the there exist two different limits  for above problem.

For  $0< x\leq 1$, we define the functions $$f(x)=\ln(1+x),\; \displaystyle g(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-x)^k}{k+1}$$ and we note that $$\begin{aligned}f(x)-g(x) &= x-\sum_{k=2}^\infty(-1)^{k+n} \frac{x^{k+n}}{k+n}\\&=x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+n} \int_0^x t^{k+n-1}dt\\&=x+(-1)^n\int_0^x t^n\left(\sum_{k=1 }^\infty(-1)^k t^{k-1} \right)dx\\&=x-(-1)^n\int_0^x\frac{t^n}{1+t} dt\end{aligned}$$ hence for $x=1$   we have then $$f(1)-g(1)=\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}=1-(-1)^n\int_0^1\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$$ Note that latter integral is know result however,here we shall derive it and  we shall show that

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(1)-g(1))^n =\begin{cases}\sqrt{e}\; \text{if }  \, n\in 2n-1 \\  \frac1{\sqrt{e}} \; \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

We solve the following integral for any $n>0$. By  polynomial long division it  is trivial to note that  $$\int_0^1\frac{t^n}{t+1}dt=(-1)^n\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{t+1}-\sum_{0\leq j\leq n}(-1)^j t^{j-1}\right)dt$$  and hence on integrating $\displaystyle \int_0^1\frac{t^n}{1+t}dt$ $$\begin{aligned}&=(-1)^n\left(\log(2) -\sum_{1\leq j\leq n} \frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\right)\\&=2^{-1}\left(-\psi\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)+\psi\left(\frac{2n+1}2\right)\right)\\&=\frac12\left(H_{\frac{n}2}-H_{\frac{n-1}2}\right)\end{aligned}$$ Further we note that $H_n\approx \gamma +\ln n +\frac1{2n}-O(n^{-2})$  with which we deduce that $$H_{\frac{n}2} -H_{\frac{n-1}2} \approx  \frac1n-\ln\left(\frac{n-1}n\right)+\frac1{n-1}$$ for all $n>1$ and hence $H_{\frac{n}{2}} -H_{\frac{n-1}2} \to \frac1n$as $n$ gets larger. Thus we have for $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(1)-g(1))^n= \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right)^n=e^{-\frac{(-1)^n}2} =\sqrt{e^{-(-1)^n}}$$
therefore  if $n$ is even we have limit as $\displaystyle \frac1{\sqrt{e}}$ and if $n$ is odd we  have limit $ \displaystyle \sqrt{e}$.

Since we have two different limits. Does it have limit ?

Thank you

Comment: I think $+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ should be $\color{#C00}{-}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$.

Comment: @robjohn,I cannot figure out to which line you are referring. Please let me know. :)

Comment: In the problem statement

Comment: the first term in the parentheses is $-\frac12$, so the general term in the parentheses seems to be $-\frac{(-1)^n}n$, not $+\frac{(-1)^n}n$

Comment: @robjohn, it's typo. I have fixed it. Thank you pointing it.:)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The alternating series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$$ is well-known to tend to $\log 2$, and the expression inside the main parenthesis oscillates around $1$. One can expect an asymptotic behavior like

$$1\pm\frac1{2n}.$$

Then taking the $n^{th}$ power, the value will alternatively rejoin $e^{1/2}$ and $e^{-1/2}$, so the limit of the sequence does not exist.

---

More precisely, if we group the terms in pairs, we have alternatively

$$S_{2n}=1+\sum_{k=2n+2}^\infty\frac1{2k(2k+1)}\sim 1+\frac1{4n}$$

and

$$S_{2n+1}=1+\sum_{k=2n+2}^\infty\frac1{2k(2k+1)}-\frac1{2n+1}\sim 1-\frac1{4n},$$ approximating the sums by integrals.

Taking the power, we have

$$S_{2n[+1]}^{2n}\sim\left(1\pm\frac1{4n}\right)^{2n}\sim e^{\pm1/2}.$$

Comment: This is much quick analysis to this problem. Thank you very much for the conclusion. :)

Comment: @Naruto: yep, but a little informal. I am trying to improve.

Comment: Can you clarify why that asymptotic expression?

Comment: @Dude: the alternating terms are $\frac1n$.

Comment: Still it remains unclear to me why :(

Comment: @Dude: perhaps the inequalities $(7)$ and $(10)$ from my answer might shed some light on why.

Answer (score 3):

**Preliminaries**

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)
\le\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}
\le\frac12\left(\frac1{2k-1}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)\tag1
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(1)$ for $k\ge n$ gives
$$
\frac1{4n}\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)\le\frac1{4n-2}\tag2
$$
Furthermore,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+3}\right)
\le\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+2}
\le\frac12\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Summing $(3)$ for $k\ge n$ gives
$$
\frac1{4n+2}\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)\le\frac1{4n}\tag4
$$

---

**Two Limits**

Inequality $(2)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log(2)+\sum_{k=2}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}k
&=1-\sum_{k=2n}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k\tag5\\
&=1-\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)\tag6\\
&=1-\left[\frac1{4n},\frac1{4n-2}\right]\tag7
\end{align}
$$
where $[a,b]$ is a number between $a$ and $b$.

Likewise, inequality $(4)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\log(2)+\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}k
&=1-\sum_{k=2n+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k\tag8\\
&=1+\sum_{k=n}^\infty\left(\frac1{2k+1}-\frac1{2k+2}\right)\tag9\\
&=1+\left[\frac1{4n+2},\frac1{4n}\right]\tag{10}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $(7)$ says that for an even number of terms in the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(2)+\sum_{k=2}^{2n-1}\frac{(-1)^k}k\right)^{2n-1}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\left[\frac1{4n},\frac1{4n-2}\right]\right)^{2n-1}\tag{11}\\[6pt]
&=e^{-1/2}\tag{12}
\end{align}
$$
and $(10)$ says that for an odd number of terms in the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\log(2)+\sum_{k=2}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^k}k\right)^{2n}
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\left[\frac1{4n+2},\frac1{4n}\right]\right)^{2n}\tag{13}\\[6pt]
&=e^{1/2}\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Conclusion**

Using $(11)$, $(13)$, and the inequality
$$
e^{\frac x{1+x}}\le1+x\le e^x\tag{15}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\log(2)+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{(-1)^k}k\right)^n
&=\left(1+(-1)^n\left[\frac1{2n+2},\frac1{2n}\right]\right)^n\tag{16}\\
&=\left\{\begin{array}{}
e^{\frac12-\left[0,\frac3{4n+6}\right]}&\text{if $n$ is even}\\
e^{-\frac12+\left[-\frac1{4n-2},\frac1{2n+2}\right]}&\text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{array}\right.\tag{17}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, the limit does not exist, but if we restrict $n$ to be even or $n$ to be odd, then each of those limits do exist.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer!

Comment: @Dude: Thanks! I fear it may have been too detailed, since it was unaccepted.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\, }
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\ln\pars{2} -
\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4} + \cdots -{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n}}}^{n} = \root{\expo{}}}:\ {\Large ?}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffd]{\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{\ln\pars{2} -
\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2} + {1 \over 3} - {1 \over 4} + \cdots -{\pars{-1}^{n} \over n}}}^{n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} +
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{2} + 1 +
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k} -
\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1  -
\sum_{k = n + 1}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}^{n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1  -
\pars{-1}^{n + 1}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k + n + 1}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1  +
\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{%
{1 \over 2k + n + 1} - {1 \over 2k + n + 2}}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{1  +
{1 \over 4}\pars{-1}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{k + n/2 + 1/2}\pars{k + n/2 + 1}}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{1  +
{1 \over 2}\pars{-1}^{n}
\bracks{\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + 1} -
\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}}}^{n}
\end{align}
Note that
\begin{align}
&\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + 1} -
\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{1 \over n} - {1 \over 2n^{2}}
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\mbox{}
\\
&\bbx{\bracks{\ln\pars{2} +
\sum_{k = 2}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over k}}^{n}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}^{n}{\color{red}{1/2} \over n}}^{n}}
\\ &
\end{align}